# CSSの:hoverでアニメーション設定した要素の中でリンク指定すると、スマホ表示ではどうなるのが正しい挙動？

Tags: android, css, html5

**Q1.下記例でリンククリックした場合、正しい挙動は？**
・アニメーションを最後まで動作させてからリンク遷移
・アニメーション途中でリンク遷移
・アニメーションせずにリンク遷移
・アニメーション内容により異なる？

**html**

```
<button class="hoge">
  <a href="/">リンク</a>
</button>
```

**css**

```
.hoge:hover {
    animation: anim 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim
```

---

**Q2.aタグを外へ出したら意味は変わるでしょうか？**

```
<a href="/">
  <button class="hoge">
    リンク
  </button>
```

**Q3.スマホの実機だけ、リンク遷移しないのですが…**
・PCやエミュレーでは動作するのですが、スマホの実機だけリンク遷移しません
・アニメーションされるが、それだけです
・どういった原因が考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: 何をアニメーションするかによって挙動が変わる可能性があるので、問題が再現する完全なコードを示すことをおすすめします。あと、スマホの実機といっても環境は色々なので具体的に書くべきです。

Answer (score 1):

スマホではhoverにあたる挙動がないため、
・アニメーションせずにリンク遷移
になると思います。
リンク遷移しないのとhoverは別の問題ではないかと思います。

というかbuttonタグとaタグを併用する必要はないのでは？

`<a href="/" class="hoge">リンク</a>`

ではいけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

スマホでは2回タップすると遷移しませんか？
端末にもよりますが、1回目のタップでhoverの動きになり、2回目で遷移すると思います。
スマホにhoverはないので。